# learning htaccess commands

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

what does ^ stand for in htaccess rewrite codes. Where can I find all htaccess entities like ^ \d etc and their meanings. I have started looking but all I can find is examples but not the explanation of basic operators.

Comment: Have you tried [the mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html#regex)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'^' refers to the match the start of the string.

\d  - match any special character, here it'll match 'd'.

You can refer[this link](http://x10hosting.com/forums/tutorials/96310-htaccess-regular-expressions.html) to write .htaccess